# Is using an inline function as fast as directly writing the function body in the code?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, inline-functions, code-size

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            m_dbLoopStart   = 0.0;
            m_dbLoopStop    = 100.0;
            m_dbLoopStep    = 0.001;
        }

        // Which of the following methods complete in a shorter time?

        void Foo1() const   // This one?
        {
            for (double x=m_dbLoopStart; x<=m_dbLoopStop; x+=m_dbLoopStep)
            {
                f(x);
            }
        }

        void Foo2() const   // Or, this one?
        {
            for (double x=m_dbLoopStart; x<=m_dbLoopStop; x+=m_dbLoopStep)
            {
                2.0 * x + 1.0;
            }
        }

    private:
        double m_dbLoopStart, m_dbLoopStop, m_dbLoopStep;

        inline static double f(double x)
        {
            return 2.0 * x + 1.0;
        }
};
```

Between `Foo1()` and `Foo2()`, which one would complete faster?

Comment: If there's any difference at all, then you need a better compiler.

Comment: These should both result in very similar assembly (if not the same).

Comment: The only difference is that an inline function may not *necessarily* be inlined, whereas with directly inserted code then the compiler has no choice.

Comment: As fast as manual copy-and-paste? Yes (assuming the complier really inlined)! Faster than not inlining at all? It depends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline functions may be faster because they avoid the cost of a function call and return overhead.  Remember that compilers may choose not to inline functions.

In most translators, function parameters must be passed and space allocated for the parameters and any function local storage.  On the return side, the function local variables must be removed and usually a value returned.

For simple functions, such as getters and setters, the overhead of the function call and return are greater than the code in the function.  Thus inlining will speed up these functions.

Inline functions also remove the branch instruction to call the function.  This reduces the chance of the processor clearing out the instruction cache / pipeline.  Although modern processors have implemented algorithms to reduce the negative impact of branch instructions.

In my programming practices, I inline small (3 line or smaller) methods.  If I'm going to inline for performance reasons, I'll profile before inlining.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the use of "inline" is superfluous because functions defined in the class definition are inline by default.
Having said this, defining a function as inline doesn't mean that the function must be inlined and not defining it as inline doesn't mean that the compiler will not inline the function.

As others already said, in this case, it won't make a difference, with optimization on, even the loop should be optimized to being no code, with x being assigned the value of m_dbLoopStop (whatever x may be).

Answer (score 2):

if you use an inline function, the compiler may still opt not to copy the body of the function itself, thus causing a function call. If you write the function body explicitly then for sure no functions are called.

So strictly theoretically, its faster.

Comment: Then again, the compiler might actually have a good reason for not inlining a function. For example, if the function body is huge, the compiler may not inline it because of cache effects. Modern CPUs are quite complex, so their performance characteristics are not always intuitive. It might actually be faster to not inline a particular function.

Comment: @Insilico: Yes, but in this particular case, it's best to inline.

Answer (score 1):

There are often slight semantic differences between calling inline functions with parameters vs simply using copy/paste code or #define macros.  For example, consider the macro and function:

```
extern void some_extern_function(int x);
#define foo1(x) (some_extern_function((x)), some_extern_function((x)))
void inline foo2(int x) {some_extern_function(x); some_extern_function(x); }
```

Now suppose one invokes them:

```
  extern volatile int some_volatile_int;
  foo1(some_volatile_int);
  foo2(some_volatile_int);
```

In this scenario, the inline function `foo2` must make a copy of `some_volatile_int` and then pass that copy to both calls of `some_extern_function`.  By contrast, the macro must load `some_volatile_int` twice.  Depending upon the calling conventions, either approach may be faster than the other.